# Determine if the following autonomous differential equation has periodic solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems

> Let $\begin{cases}
> x'=-y\\
> y'=x+y^{2}
> \end{cases}$ be an autonomous system. Determine whether or not is has periodic solutions. Hint: Consider the differential equations of the orbit: $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}-y$

I just started learning about about autonomous systems, and I have no idea how to approach this. I assume I need to use Poincare-Bendixon but I don't see how to use the hint (or even understand it). Bendixon's criteria doesn't help either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Doug Am I supposed to think of $y$ as function of $x$?

Comment: @Doug So basically I'm trying to solve the equation $z'=-\frac{x}{z}-z$?

Comment: my apologies.  My approach was incorrect.  Please see answer from Cesareo.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

$$
\cases{
x x' = -x y\\
y y' = x y + y^3
}
$$

after addition

$$
\frac 12(x^2+y^2)'= \frac 14 (y^4)'
$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate how this helps me?

Comment: The radius is always increasing.

Comment: and why did you have to modify the equation itself/

Comment: Originally we have two differential equations.